How I change the entry point mentioned in the form after taking the scheduling for Schengen visa?
How can I change the entry point after filling the application form and scheduling the appointment of Schengen visa?

I doubt you can without cancelling the application and starting again. Why do you want to do this? Your first point of entry does not need to be the country that issued your visa

It may depend on the reason. As Taveller wrote: if it is just a small adjustment (e.g. because flight) it is not a problem. If you are changing plans: e.g. visiting countries A, B, instead of X, Y, it is often a problem (especially if you are asking visa to country X or Y. (we assume same purpose, else you may need to change other items, but so not the question you are asking).
